# a function that returns number of sums of a certain number.py

Tags: python

I need to write a function that returns the number of ways of reaching a certain number by adding numbers of a list. For example:

```
print(p([3,5,8,9,11,12,20], 20))
should return:5
```

The code I wrote is:

```
def pow(lis):
    power = [[]]
    for lst in lis:
        for po in power:
            power = power + [list(po)+[lst]]
    return power

def p(lst, n):
    counter1 = 0
    counter2 = 0
    power_list = pow(lst)
    print(power_list)
    for p in power_list:
        for j in p:
            counter1 += j
        if counter1 == n:
            counter2 += 1
            counter1 == 0
        else:
            counter1 == 0
    return counter2
```

`pow()` is a function that returns all of the subsets of the list and `p` should return the number of ways to reach the number n. I keep getting an output of zero and I don't understand why. I would love to hear your input for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `pow` is a built-in function, you might want to pick a different name. In any event, if all of the numbers are known to be positive, going over all subsets is overkill.

Comment: Also -- unless this is homework and you are expected to do everything from scratch, using the `itertools` module is the easiest way to enumerate subsets.

Comment: `counter1 == 0` should be `counter1 = 0` (two times). Closing for typo. Also, can be simplified to `counter2 = sum(sum(p) == n for p in power_list)`

Answer (score 1):

A one pass solution with one counter, which minimize additions.

```
def one_pass_sum(L,target):
   sums = [0]
   cnt = 0
   for x in L:
       for y in sums[:]: 
           z = x+y
           if z <= target : 
                sums.append(z)
                if z == target : cnt += 1
   return cnt
```

This way if `n=len(L)`, you make less than `2^n` additions against `n/2 * 2^n`  by calculating all the sums.

**EDIT :**

A more efficient solution, that just counts ways. The idea is to see that if there is `k` ways to make `z-x`, there is `k` more way to do `z` when `x` arise.

```
def enhanced_sum_with_lists(L,target):
    cnt=[1]+[0]*target # 1 way to make 0
    for x in L:
        for z in range(target,x-1,-1):  # [target, ..., x+1, x]
            cnt[z] += cnt[z-x]
    return cnt[target]
```

But order is important : `z` must be considered descendant here, to have the good counts (Thanks to PM 2Ring).

This can be very fast (`n*target` additions) for big lists.

For example :

```
>>> enhanced_sum_with_lists(range(1,100),2500)
875274644371694133420180815
```

is obtained in 61 ms. It will take the age of the universe to compute it by the first method.

Comment: If you want just the result for target, return cnt[target]. I edit the post for clarity.

Comment: Thank's for detecting  this error, I correct and try to explain it. It's about 400x faster than a list approach on `*args = range(1,41),70`, because few sums are calculated.

Comment: Nice work! I'd give you another upvote if I could. :) BTW, your `sum_with_dict` is about 6 times faster than my `subset_sums` with `range(1,41),70` on Python 3.6.0 on my old 32 bit single core machine.

Comment: I finally give a list version, because the enhancement come from algorithm, not from dict, which is more difficult to understand in a first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134349/discussion-between-b-m-and-pm-2ring).

Comment: I agree that the final list version is easier to understand than the dict version, and its speed is very similar. BTW, you should visit the [SO Python Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) some time.

Answer (score 1):

There are two typos in your code: `counter1 == 0` is a boolean, it does not reset anything.

This version should work:

```
def p(lst, n):
    counter2 = 0
    power_list = pow(lst)       
    for p in power_list:
        counter1 = 0 #reset the counter for every new subset
        for j in p:
            counter1 += j
        if counter1 == n:
            counter2 += 1
    return counter2
```

Comment: "You reset counter1 only when you have a total of n" This is not true; he resets `counter1` in both cases, in the `if` and in the `else` -- or he would, if it were not for the simple typo.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I failed to see the first typo ^^

Answer (score 1):

As tobias_k and Faibbus mentioned, you have a typo: `counter1 == 0` instead of `counter1 = 0`, in two places. The `counter1 == 0` produces a boolean object of `True` or `False`, but since you don't assign the result of that expression the result gets thrown away. It doesn't raise a `SyntaxError`, since an expression that isn't assigned is legal Python.

As John Coleman and B. M. mention it's not efficient to create the full powerset and then test each subset to see if it has the correct sum. This approach is ok if the input sequence is small, but it's very slow for even moderately sized sequences, and if you actually create a list containing the subsets rather than using a generator and testing the subsets as they're yielded you'll soon run out of RAM.

B. M.'s first solution is quite efficient since it doesn't produce subsets that are larger than the target sum. (I'm not sure what B. M. is doing with that dict-based solution...).

But we can enhance that approach by sorting the list of sums. That way we can break out of the inner `for` loop as soon as we detect a sum that's too high. True, we need to sort the `sums` list on each iteration of the outer `for` loop, but fortunately Python's TimSort is very efficient, and it's optimized to handle sorting a list that contains sorted sub-sequences, so it's ideal for this application.

```
def subset_sums(seq, goal):
    sums = [0]
    for x in seq:
        subgoal = goal - x
        temp = []
        for y in sums:
            if y > subgoal:
                break
            temp.append(y + x)
        sums.extend(temp)
        sums.sort()
    return sum(1 for y in sums if y == goal)

# test

lst = [3, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12, 20]
total = 20
print(subset_sums(lst, total))

lst = range(1, 41)
total = 70
print(subset_sums(lst, total))
```

**output**

```
5
28188
```

With `lst = range(1, 41)` and `total = 70`, this code is around 3 times faster than the B.M. lists version.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset_generator(i):
    for subset in chain.from_iterable(combinations(i, r) for r in range(len(i)+1)):
        yield set(subset)

def count_sum(s, cnt):
    return sum(1 for i in powerset_generator(s) if sum(k for k in i) == cnt)

print(count_sum(set([3,5,8,9,11,12,20]), 20))
```

Comment: FWIW, code-only answers aren't well-received on SO. You're more likely to get up-votes (& less likely to get down-votes) if you add some text explaining your answer.